# using a variable in a SUBQUERY is returning more than one row

Tags: mysql, mysql-variables

I'm trying to reuse the `@FleetNumber` variable to get the Truck's Trailer registration Number through the fleet number `<fleetnumber>T` eg.393T. The Trailer has the fleet number of the `<fleetnumber>L` eg. 393L. This following query works if the main query returns a singular record, but I need it to return multiple records.

When removing the where clause I get the error `Subquery returns more than 1 row`. The query needs to get the trailer Registration for every fleet number that is in the `HANDOVER` table.

```
SELECT
    h.TRANSACTION_NUMBER,
    a.RECORD_ID AS `A_ASSET_ID`

    @FleetNumber := a.FLEET_NUMBER,

    (
        SELECT a1.REGISTRATION_NUMBER
        FROM newtodme_newton_web_portal.ASSETS a1
        WHERE a1.FLEET_NUMBER = REPLACE(@FleetNumber, 'T', 'L')
    ) AS `TRAILER_REG`

FROM newtodme_newton_hand_over.HANDOVERS h
LEFT JOIN newtodme_newton_web_portal.ASSETS a ON h.ASSET_ID = a.RECORD_ID;
/*WHERE h.TRANSACTION_NUMBER = 4000*/
```

Comment: [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055)

Comment: Why are you using the variable? Why not just `a1.FLEET_NUMBER = REPLACE(a.FLEET_NUMBER, 'T', 'L')`?

Comment: UDV usage is incorrect. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html *The order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined.*

Comment: 'When removing the where clause I get the error Subquery returns more than 1 row' - That's correct and normal behaviour ,you need a different approach. Publishing sample data and expected outcome as text would be a start